# Rails.Share variable between 2 models(Validation)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So having some troubles how to resolve my `puzzle`.

I'm having 2 models

1) Mode1.rb

```
class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "Model1"
  set_sequence_name "Model1"  

    module Validate
      def validate_discount
        errors.add(:discount, "#blank") if discount.blank?
      end
    end
end
```

2) Model2.rb

```
class Model2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Model1::Validate

  validate :validate_discount

end
```

What i need? The trouble is that on submit page operating `model2`, so i need to execute validation from there to get proper error display, but as `discount` exists only in `model1` i need to pass it to `model2`

The error what i get is now:

```
undefined local variable or method `discount' for #<Model2:0x12c952f8>
```

Might i need somehow pass it through the controller? I mean smth like this:

```
Model2.new
Model2["discount"] = 20
Model2.discount
```

I'm stuck now.

Comment: What is the reason of validation property that doesn't exist in Model2?

Comment: @RomanAlekseiev Я обьясню на русском, а потом переведу на английском для остальных. Смотрите, у меня есть форма которая завязана на 2 модель, соотвественно все операции и валидации проходят через неё. На этой форме я использую первую модель для сохраннения некоторых данных, но по сколько модель не обрабатывается, то и ошибка тоже(выводится не на странице, а просто выдаёт новую страницу где описана вся ошибка и тд), тем самым вот и задача, нужно всё вызывать из под 2 модели. Если нужно, я могу предоставить скриншоты чтобы вы поняли о чём идёт речь.

Comment: `This text is just translation that i wrote above`So there is form that uses 2 model, so all validation/operations comes from it. On this form i'm using 1 model to save some data, but like model 1 is not getting processed on that form, so that's why i need to pass value in model 2. Maybe there is an alternative, but now the error is shown not on a page witch is formatted, but like "whole error page" where you can see all in details. If needed i can show screenshots, so you would understand it better.

Comment: The purpose of this operation is still questionable, however, `validates_associated` might be something to look at?

Comment: @VladimirTagai Might be, but what is the main difference between `validate ` and `validates_associated `? I don't know how to explain my problem, hard :D. But what i know, i need to pass value from one model, to second. Maybe i can record video or create images, i think it would be more useful.

Comment: If model2 has no field `discount`, why do you need to validate it? Are model1 and model2 associated? Small side-remark: using the actual code/example you have to solve could also make it clearer for us how model1 and model2 relate. Is one in a legacy database? why the explicit tablename/sequence in model1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `attr_accessor` for this purpose. With that you can set and get value of `discount` attribute.

```rb
class Model2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Model1::Validate

  attr_accessor :discount

  validate :validate_discount

end
```

With this you can call:

```rb
model2 = Model2.new
model2.discount = params[:discount] #or whatever you set value for discount
```

And then validate it with your `Model1::Validate` module.

Comment: Thank you, you gave me idea just to pass variable inside `update_attributes` and i just operate now in 1 model.